# Avoiding type casting in a for-comprehension on a sequence of mixed items

Tags: scala, filter, for-comprehension

I know that typing is a big deal in Scala, and ideally you go around type casting or any messy solutions by using things like Pattern Matching. However, I can't understand how could I go about it if I am iterating through a list or sequence of items which are a subtype of a common super type, and just want those of a specific subtype in a Sequence of that subtype. I don't think I can put a pattern match in a `for-comprehension` to achieve this.

So lets say for example I have these classes:

```
sealed abstract class SuperType
case class SubtypeA extends SuperType
case class SubtypeB extends SuperType
```

I have a `Seq[SuperType]` and I want to get a `Seq` of just the `SubtypeA` instances, so a `Seq[SubTypeA]`, so that then I can loop through it and execute a method provided by `SubTypeA` for all elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala has a [function called `collect`](http://ochafik.com/blog/?p=393) that does exactly what you need. It takes a Partial Function as a parameter and if the Partial Function is defined at the element then it applies it. If it isn't then it skips it. Since matching is essentially a Partial Function we can use this to our advantage:

```
val list: Seq[SuperType] = ???
val listOfAtypes = list.collect({ case a: SubtypeA => a })
```

`{ case a: SubtypeA => a }` is a PartialFunction[SuperType, SubtypeA].

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I am still a beginner in Scala so still need to get used to all these dark secrets :)

Comment: Note that the `({...})` syntax is redundant, you only need the curly braces:  `list.collect{ case a: SubtypeA => a }`

Comment: @dhg Yes, you're right. I just wanted to emphasize that `{ case ... }` will become a `PartialFunction` that needs to be passed to `collect`.

Comment: this is the case when `<-` is used, and what's the *general* way to deal with `... ; e=s.getE; if e.isInstanceOf[SubE]; subE = e.asInstanceOf[SubE]` where `s.getE` will return a type `E` which  is a parent type of `SubE`, and `SubE` is NOT a case class therefore internal pattern matching inside `for-comprehension` is not possible? Should I have to make use `e < - List(s.getE).collect{...}` in that way?